# Server 22.04 running on Azure VM shows private IP of server as all visitor remote IPs

Tags: networking, server, apache2, 22.04, azure

We've got an ubuntu 22.04 server running on a VM within MS Azure.  Its a standard webserver setup with nothing fancy added on.  We're having an issue with anywhere that REMOTE_ADDR is being called will return the 10.0.X.X private LAN address of the machine, instead of the actual remote IP from the external user.

I've searched all over and seen several references to editing the apache config to use `mod_remoteip` and `X-Forwarded-For`.  I've followed those instructions, but still only see our internal IP in the logs.

Is this an ubuntu config in 22.04 that would have changed since 20.04?  We have an identical server running 20.04 that we just migrated from, and didn't have these same issues.

Any pointers would be appreciated here.  Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  20.04 and 22.04 Server are the two OSs in use in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this out, the issue was caused by BitDefender Endpoint Protection for Linux.

This is a *feature* of their Network Protection module within the security suite.  After several tests and back and forth with BitDefender support, their only suggestion was to "turn off Network Security in the package."

Obviously, this isn't a helpful solution for a public facing web server, so we've simply moved away from BitDefender's product all together on this server.